# ¿Como paso una palabra tipo String a char para sacar las letras e insertarla en la clase vista (usando MVC)?

Tags: java, array, hashmap

bueno mi duda es de como poder obtener los char de una palabra en un arreglo tipo String, ya que se me pide usar solo array, array String o un hashmap para poder crea un juego (el ahorcado) utilizando el MVC en donde la clase controlador almacene las palabras y demás operaciones que se necesiten para la clase vista.
ademas de hacer visibles las letras correspondientes que se inserten una vez adivinada.

Esto es lo que llevo, por mas que lo intento no logro dividir la palabra a Char (soy nuevo en esto de la programacion por lo que aun no logro entender bien el uso de los arrays (arreglos) y hashmap).

**CLASE CONTROLADOR**

```
public class controlador {
int X=0;
int intentos=10;
Random lol = new Random();
private String[] palabras = new String[10];


public controlador(){
    palabrasParaJugar();
}

private void palabrasParaJugar(){
  palabras[0]="software";
  palabras[1]="Dungeon";
  palabras[2]="Programa";
  palabras[3]="Arreglo";
  palabras[4]="privados";
  palabras[5]="Integer";
  palabras[6]="Mapas";
}

public int getIntentos() {
    return intentos;
}

public void setIntentos(int intentos) {
    this.intentos = intentos;
}

public String getPalabra(int indice) {
    return palabras[indice];
}
public void Divididas(){
    Palabras_Divididas();
}
private void Palabras_Divididas(){
int lal = lol.nextInt(10);
char[] Division = DP(palabras[lal]);
        for (int i = 0; i < Division.length; i++) {
        }}
private static char[] DP(String palAzar){
    char[] letras;
    letras = new char[palAzar.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < palAzar.length(); i++){
        letras[i] = palAzar.charAt(i);
    }
    return letras;
}

}
```

`

**CLASE VISTA**

```
    `
   public vista() {
    initComponents();
    ocultarCasillas();
    mostrarCasillas();
    A= new controlador();
    private void   mostrarCasillas(){
    controlador control = new controlador();
    int indice = (int)(Math.random()*6);
    palabra_a_buscar = control.getPalabra(indice);
    switch(palabra_a_buscar.length()){
        case 5:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 6:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra6.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 7:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra6.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra7.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 8:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra6.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra7.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra8.setVisible(true);
            break;
        case 9:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra6.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra7.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra8.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra9.setVisible(true);
            break;
         case 10:
            txtLetra1.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra2.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra3.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra4.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra5.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra6.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra7.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra8.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra9.setVisible(true);
            txtLetra10.setVisible(true);
            break;
            default:
            break;

}


}
private void   ocultarCasillas(){
txtLetra1.setVisible(false);
txtLetra2.setVisible(false);
txtLetra3.setVisible(false);
txtLetra4.setVisible(false);
txtLetra5.setVisible(false);
txtLetra6.setVisible(false);
txtLetra7.setVisible(false);
txtLetra8.setVisible(false);
txtLetra9.setVisible(false);
txtLetra10.setVisible(false);

}
public void pantalla(){
Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
    preferredSize.width= 400;
    preferredSize.height= 350;
    getContentPane().setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
    getContentPane().setPreferredSize(preferredSize);

    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());
     this.setVisible(true);
}`
```

esto es lo que llevo, primeramente use hashmap que fue mi primera opción, pero no supe como utilizarlo de allí pase a arreglos, pero no se como hacer que pasen a carácter.

Answer (score 0):

No esto al 100% seguro de lo que pides, aun así entiendo que necesitas un array de caracteres, en el cuál se almacenen cada caracter en la posición correspondiente. Si es así, haciendo uso de un método que presenta el tipo String, puedes conseguir un flujo de datos, este flujo contiene el valor en unicode de cada caracter. Una vez ahi, conviertes cada valor a un caracter y lo almacenas en una lista o un array.
A continuación te presento un método de ejemplo y su correspondiente salida por pantalla/consola.

```
public static List<Character> getWordChars(String palabra) {
    List<Character> res = new ArrayList<Character>();
    palabra.chars().boxed().forEach(i -> res.add(Character.toChars(i)[0]));
    return res;
}
```

[image: Salida por pantalla del método]

Answer (score 0):

Los Strings en Java son objetos (no tipos primitivos). Como tal, tienen diversos métodos para trabajar con ellos.

String tiene un método que se llama [toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) que hace exactamente lo que quieres.

Un saludo.